# Set choice box to default value in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying out JavaFX for the first time. I have some textfields to allow users to enter data and a choice box which gives the user some items to pick from. When I click the "New" button, it will clear the text fields so that the user can enter new data. I also want the choice box to go back to the default value when the "New" button is selected. Is there a method I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used getSelectionModel().selectFirst() to set the choice box back to the first value (which is the default in my case). However, if the default for your choice box is not the first value, you can use getSelectionModel().select(2), for example, if your default value is in the second index.

Answer (score 0):

Other way (easier) to do it is to set same string like your choice and use choice.select(string) for example:

```
String lang = "English";
Choice jezyk=new Choice();
jezyk.add("polski");
jezyk.add("English");
jezyk.select(lang);
```